# How to use grep to search for a line with one of two words but not both?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I want to search for lines with 'word1' XOR 'word2' in a text file. So it should output lines with word1, word2 but not the lines with both of these words. I wanted to use the XOR but I do not know how to write that in linux command line.

I tried:

```
grep 'word1\|word2' text.txt
grep word1 word2 text.txt
grep word1 text.txt | grep word2
grep 'word1\^word2' text.txt
```

and many more, but could not get sucess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`grep 'word1\|word2' text.txt` searches for lines containing `word1` or `word2`. This includes lines that contain both.

`grep word1 text.txt | grep word2` searches for lines containing `word1` and `word2`. The two words can overlap (e.g. `foobar` contains `foo` and `ob`). Another way to search for lines containing both words, but only in a non-overlapping way, is to search for them in either order: `grep 'word1.*word2\|word2.*word1' text.txt`

`grep word1 text.txt | grep -v word2` searches for lines containing `word1` but not `word2`. The `-v` option tells grep to keep non-matching lines and remove matching lines, instead of the opposite. This gives you half the results you wanted. By adding the symmetric search, you get all the lines containing exactly one of the words.

```
grep word1 text.txt | grep -v word2
grep word2 text.txt | grep -v word1
```

Alternatively, you can start from the lines containing either word, and remove the lines containing both words. Given the building blocks above, this is easy if the words don't overlap.

```
grep 'word1\|word2' text.txt | grep -v 'word1.*word2\|word2.*word1'
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. The other answers are also very interesting so ill look into them. Thank you everyone for contributing.

Answer (score 17):

With GNU `awk`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {foo,bar}{bar,foo} neither | gawk 'xor(/foo/,/bar/)'
foofoo
barbar
```

Or portably:

```
awk '((/foo/) + (/bar/)) % 2'
```

With a `grep` with support for `-P` (PCRE):

```
grep -P '^((?=.*foo)(?!.*bar)|(?=.*bar)(?!.*foo))'
```

With `sed`:

```
sed '
  /foo/{
    /bar/d
    b
  }
  /bar/!d'
```

If you want to consider whole words only (that there is neither `foo` nor `bar` in `foobar` or `barbar` for instance), you'd need to decide how those words are delimited. If it's by any character other than letters, digits and underscore like the `-w` option of many `grep` implementation does, then you'd change those to:

```
gawk 'xor(/\<foo\>/,/\<bar\>/)'
awk '((/(^|[^[:alnum:]_)foo([^[:alnum:]_]|$)/) + \
      (/(^|[^[:alnum:]_)bar([^[:alnum:]_]|$)/)) % 2'
grep -P '^((?=.*\bfoo\b)(?!.*\bbar\b)|(?=.*\bbar\b)(?!.*\bfoo\b))'
```

For `sed` that becomes a bit complicated unless you have a `sed` implementation like GNU `sed`  that supports `\<`/`\>` as word boundaries like GNU `awk` does.

Comment: Stephane, please write a book about shell scripting!

Comment: Sorry I only started command line a few weeks ago. How would I force it to only search for words? I tried -Pw and -wP but this gave me the wrong output. I also tried to use ' ' between *word1/*word2 and around word1/word2.

Comment: @Lukali, see edit.

Answer (score 2):

A bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash 
while (( $# )); do
    a=0 ; [[ $1 =~ foo ]] && a=1 
    b=0 ; [[ $1 =~ bar ]] && b=1
    (( a ^ b )) && echo "$1"
    shift
done
```

To test it:

```
$ ./script {foo,bar}\ {foo,bar} neither
foo foo
bar bar
```